# Space between two divs in the same row

Tags: css

I have this pretty simple code - [**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vBngZ/6/).

CSS:

```
.subcontent > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
.orangebox {
    width: 55%;
    background-color: red;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
.bluebox {
    width: 43%;
    background-color: blue;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
.spacer{
    width: 1%;   
}
```

Well, in the code you can see two type of boxes, one with the style "orangebox" and another one beside it in the same line with the style "bluebox", and both have the style "display: table-cell".
Between these two boxes there's the "spacer" that place space between them with the width 1%.
The only problem comes when you zoom in/out in the webpage(CTRL + or -), the spacer on zoom out start to get bigger than 1%(you can realize it easily), and on zoom out the spacer get smaller with the width and when you zoom in deeply the spacer disappear and the two boxes overlap.
Is there any solution to set the space between the two boxes a fixed space?

Comment: Unless you set fixed `px` you cannot prevent this, as 1% of the screen when zoomed in is next to nothing.

Comment: still, when you switch the width from present to pixels the same issue occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend setting `border-spacing: 10px;` (or any amount that you'd like) on the parent element that is set to `display: table;`. This is the most effective way to space elements that are using table properties.

If you need more control over your spacing than border-spacing provides, you may need to consider using something other than table-cell for your layout, so hopefully that works out for you!

Here's an update to your fiddle demonstrating the use of border-spacing:

http://jsfiddle.net/vBngZ/7/

Comment: When you zoom out in the new results of your code the space just get reduced

Comment: I am seeing a consistent border, using google chrome. The way that css is handled when the browser zooms is largely up to the browser.

Comment: Well, it's not the best solution but it's better than the spacer and it's a great one because on zoom in the space's width stay as it is, I have only one last problem with this solution, how could I set the left border space as 0px(you can see there's extra space on the sides of the boxes and I want to remove it so the space will be placed ONLY between the boxes)

Comment: Try setting margin: -10px; (make that number equal to the border-spacing) on the parent element. This should negate the effects of the spacing on the outer edges.